# Update git submodules when superproject is in detached head

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to programmatically work with Git repositories with submodules.

Just to clarify, this is not a bare clone, I am doing a full clone with recursive mode.

The main project is always checked out in the detached head depending on the user given commit SHA at runtime with git recursive clone.

The problem is the submodules are not updating for some reason. For example, with `git log` inside the submodule folder I do see the commit from super project showing up but the files haven't been updated.

This is the command I used

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --force --merge
```

I tried the default `checkout` option too but no use. Any idea how do I guarantee to get the submodule updated to the commit SHA super-project is pointing it to and also make sure the files are updated. Or perhaps I am missing something obvious.

**Git log in submodule project's repository locally**
[image]

**Git log on the server in submodule folder of checked out super-project**
[image]

But if I open the changed file on the server, it has not been updated to reflect the change in this commit.

Comment: Server repositories are normally `--bare`, which prompts the question: How are you looking at the file on the server? With no work-tree there are no ordinary-format files.

Comment: @torek it is not a bare clone, I am cloning programmatically myself on the server and local dev setup alike. It's a normal git clone.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly mistake on my part, unfortunately. When executing the submodules update command programmatically from a different folder, instead of using `-C <path>` option I was using `--git-dir <path>` option which was incorrect. Hence the submodules never got updated, neither there was any error.

It had nothing to do with submodules after all

Wrong command

```
git --git-dir <PATH-TO-REPO-FOLDER>.git submodule update --init --recursive --force
```

Corrected command

```
git -C <PATH-TO-REPO-FOLDER> submodule update --init --recursive --force
```